# magento magmi unable to upload multiple image via csv

Tags: magento, magmi

I am using magmi for multiple image upload, but I am unable to upload images, there is only one image uploading. Please help me with example.

Thanks

Comment: show your csv file with some actual data.

Comment: Please don't expect us to help you without providing any actual data or details to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Max, make sure that your csv should have media_gallery field and it should have multiple image url with (;) semicolon seprator like

```
/extraimg1.jpg;/extraimg2.jpg
```

and make sure 'Image attributes processor' option on magmi page is checked.